# Prove that $\Bbb{Z}/p^k \Bbb{Z} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} A $ is isomorphic to the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group of order $n$ and let $p^k$ be the largest power of the prime $p$ dividing $n$. Then $\Bbb{Z}/p^k \Bbb{Z} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} A $ is isomorphic to the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$.
It has an answer here.
[$\Bbb{Z}/p^k \Bbb{Z} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} A $ is isomorphic to the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579568/bbbz-pk-bbbz-otimes-bbbz-a-is-isomorphic-to-the-sylow-p-subgro).

But when I was trying to prove it I have taken a map $f: \Bbb{Z}/p^k \Bbb{Z} \times A \to A$
s.t $(\bar n,a) \mapsto na$. This is bilinear over $\Bbb Z$ hence induces a map $F:\Bbb{Z}/p^k \Bbb{Z} \otimes_{\Bbb{Z}} A \to A$. Now my question is; is $Im(F)$ has order $p^k$. How to show that?

Comment: Your map $f$ is not well-defined since $m\equiv n$ modulo $p^k$ does not imply that $ma=na$ for $a\in A$.

Comment: Yes you are right. The thinking was pointless. Sorry